# Binding properties in FXML with numerical operators causing "Can't resolve symbol" error

Tags: javafx

I am trying to bind the layoutX property of a label to half the width of a pane using FXML in JavaFX 12. When I use the binding expression on the property `width` with the `/` operator I receive the error `Can't resolve symbol width / 2`. How would i fix this?

Originally I had my form set in a VBox where I could set the alignment. However I am pretty used to setting positions by myself instead of giving control of the layout to the VBox. So I am trying to set the position myself.

I am able to achieve the desired result inside my java class with: `label.layoutXProperty.bind(pane.widthProperty().divide(2))`.

I am trying to bind the property in FXML to keep my classes smaller. Currently I have the following code:

```
<Pane fx:controller="jotGenerator.JotController"
      xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
      fx:id="contents">

    <padding><Insets topRightBottomLeft="50"/></padding>

    <Label text="JOT" layoutX="${contents.width / 2}"/>
</Pane>
```

The issue appears on this line `<Label text="JOT" layoutX="${contents.width / 2}"/>`

I am expecting this to bind the horizontal layout position to the half the width of the pane. However i receive an error in IntelliJ saying `Can't resolve symbol width / 2`

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah don't worry, turns out the error comes up in IntelliJ but the FXML loader can find the property anyway. You can just ignore the message I suppose.